# How to stub Swift "Trait/Mixin" method in struct/class for testing

Tags: swift, unit-testing, traits, mixins, stub

I have recently read about how to add "Traits/Mixins" to a struct/class in Swift by creating a protocol and extending that protocol with a default implementation. This is great as it allows me to add functionality to view the controller without having to add a bunch of helper objects to said view controller. My question is, how do I stub calls that are provided by these default implementations?

Here is a simple example:

```
protocol CodeCop {
  func shouldAllowExecution() -> Bool
}

extension CodeCop {
  func shouldAllowExecution() -> Bool {
    return arc4random_uniform(2) == 0
  }
}

struct Worker : CodeCop {
  func doSomeStuff() -> String {
    if shouldAllowExecution() {
       return "Cop allowed it"
     } else {
       return "Cop said no"
    }
  }
}
```

If I wanted to write two tests, one that verifies that the String "Cop allowed it" is returned by doStuff() when CodeCop does not allow execution, and another test that verifies that the String "Cop said no" is returned by doStuff() when CodeCop does not allow execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple enough to do by writing an additional protocol in your test target, called `CodeCopStub`, that inherits from `CodeCop`:

```
protocol CodeCopStub: CodeCop {
    // CodeCopStub declares a static value on the implementing type
    // that you can use to control what is returned by
    // `shouldAllowExecution()`.
    //
    // Note that this has to be static, because you can't add stored instance
    // variables in extensions.
    static var allowed: Bool { get }
}
```

Then extend `CodeCopStub`'s `shouldAllowExecution()` method, inherited from `CodeCop`, to return a value depending on that new static variable `allowed`. This overrides the original `CodeCop` implementation for any type that implements `CodeCopStub`.

```
extension CodeCopStub {
    func shouldAllowExecution() -> Bool {
        // We use `Self` here to refer to the implementing type (`Worker` in
        // this case).
        return Self.allowed
    }
}
```

All you have left to do at this point is to make `Worker` conform to `CodeCopStub`:

```
extension Worker: CodeCopStub {
    // It doesn't matter what the initial value of this variable is, because
    // you're going to set it in every test, but it has to have one because
    // it's static.
    static var allowed: Bool = false
}
```

Your tests will then look something like this:

```
func testAllowed() {
    // Create the worker.
    let worker = Worker()
    // Because `Worker` has been extended to conform to `CodeCopStub`, it will
    // have this static property. Set it to true to cause
    // `shouldAllowExecution()` to return `true`.
    Worker.allowed = true

    // Call the method and get the result.
    let actualResult = worker.doSomeStuff()
    // Make sure the result was correct.
    let expectedResult = "Cop allowed it"
    XCTAssertEqual(expectedResult, actualResult)
}

func testNotAllowed() {
    // Same stuff as last time...
    let worker = Worker()
    // ...but you tell it not to allow it.
    Worker.allowed = false

    let actualResult = worker.doSomeStuff()
    // This time, the expected result is different.
    let expectedResult = "Cop said no"
    XCTAssertEqual(expectedResult, actualResult)
}
```

Remember that all of this code should go in your *test target*, not your main target. By putting it in your test target, none of it will affect your original code, and no modification to the original is required.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if that is what you are looking for, but one way you can test this behavior **without updating your code** is by updating your project structure the following way:

- Keep the `CodeCop` protocol in one file (let's say `CodeCop.swift`) and add the extension code into another one (CodeCop+shouldAllowExecution.swift)
- While `CodeCop.swift` is linked to both your main target and your test target, `CodeCop+shouldAllowExecution.swift` is only in the main target.
- Create a test file `CodeCopTest.swift`, only available in the test target, who contains another default implementation of `shouldAllowExecution` that will help you run your test.

Here's a potential `CodeCopTest.swift` file

```
import XCTest

fileprivate var shouldCopAllowExecution: Bool = false

fileprivate extension CodeCop {

    func shouldAllowExecution() -> Bool {
        return shouldCopAllowExecution
    }
}

class PeopleListDataProviderTests: XCTestCase {

    var codeCop: CodeCop!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        codeCop = CodeCop()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        codeCop = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testWhenCopAllows() {
        shouldCopAllowExecution = true
        XCTAssertEqual(codeCop.doSomeStuff(), "Cop allowed it", "Cop should say 'Cop allowed it' when he allows execution")
    }

    func testWhenCopDenies() {
        shouldCopAllowExecution = false
        XCTAssertEqual(codeCop.doSomeStuff(), "Cop said no", "Cop should say 'Cop said no' when he does not allow execution")
    }
}
```